# Encoding arabic using UTF8 $lang

Tags: php, utf-8

I'm trying to translate a PHP file from English to Arabic (in UTF8),
but it doesn't work.

For example,

```
<?php echo $lang['اقتراحات']?>
```

'**اقتراحات**' = '**Suggestions**' in English

But when I remove `$lang` it work's correctly:

```
<?php echo 'اقتراحات'?>
```

and there is an external file with `$lang` - english.php.

```
$lang["Suggestions"] = "Suggestions";
$lang["Enter_Comment"] = "Enter your comment";
$lang["messaged_you"] = "<b> %s </b> messaged you";
$lang["Welcome_Window_Title"] = "Welcome";
$lang["No_Suggestions_Found"] = "No suggestions found";
```

and this is my arabic.php

```
$lang["Suggestions"] = "اقتراحات";
$lang["years_old"] = "عام";
$lang["Male"] = "رجل";
$lang["Female"] = "امرأة";
$lang["Hello"] = "مرحبا";
```

But it Doesn't work Correctly

Is there is any way to add `utf8` to `$lang` - arabic.php.

and here is my sample code 
https://bitbucket.org/snippets/th3prof/nRrGA

Comment: "Doesn't work Correctly" doesn't correctly describe a specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

PHP6 was supposed to enable utf8 in variable name but has never been brought to life because the feature did not interest so many people.

In your case, I can't really see what you are trying to do. You should use a proper English name (or at least a roman character word) as a key for translation:

```
<?php echo $lang['Suggestions']?>
```

Then in your languages file (that will be included before the template is rendered, you should just create the array to be displayed later on.

english.php

```
$lang["Enter_Comment"] = "Enter your comment";
$lang["messaged_you"] = "<b> %s </b> messaged you";
$lang["Welcome_Window_Title"] = "Welcome";
$lang["Suggestions"] = "Suggestions";
```

arabic.php

```
$lang["Suggestions"] = "اقتراحات";
```

Comment: I Want to add utf8 To $lang

Comment: What IDE or text editor are you using? If all your files are in UTF8, you don't have to worry about anything. I just don't see what you use <?php echo $lang['اقتراحات']?> for... The echo contains the key here, which outputs whatever is associated to the key. Have you got a code sample hosted somewhere (github/bitbucket)?

Comment: Im using Rapid php 2015 
and here is my snippet 
https://bitbucket.org/snippets/th3prof/nRrGA

Comment: Your content looks fine to me. I guess the language files are included somewhere core/config/config.php, core/config/config-theme.php or core/system.php. What exactly is the problem you have? In your first post the problem was because you tried to output $lang['اقتراحات'], which does not make sense, but there are no problem with using roman character keys. I am not used to your IDE, but you should check if your files are UTF8 without bom.

Comment: this is my problem 
http://i.prntscr.com/d33083635bd243b1b0a262f1929612bc.png
when i choose arabic language from array
and i checked that my files are UTF8

Comment: Have you got any better error message (from apache or PHP logs)? This is an error with the server config or file access rights...

Comment: No Sir , i haven't got any errors from apache or PHP logs , maybe it is a problem with file access right's